# Old non-flat theme in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Does anyone know if it's possible to get Bootstrap 2.x non-flat (with 3d-ish effect) theme back into Bootstrap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 comes with a `bootstrap-theme.css` file that gives you ***most*** of the 2.3.2 styles back

[See this example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/)

Just include the `theme` file in your project after the `boostrap.css` file.